# Dynamic filter condition in BigQuery procedure

Tags: sql, stored-procedures, google-bigquery

There is a procedure that gets the required data and then insert into table: 
Is it possible to have a parameter that leads to certain filter condition, how can I achieve that? 
For example, creating a new parameter called `condition` that if user type 1, the procedure will use filter 1 etc.
please see the code example below:

```
CREATE OR REPLACE PROCEDURE `peterwu.UDP_mem_profile_package`
                            (table_name STRING
                             , title_name STRING
                             , status_start_dt DATE
                             , status_end_dt DATE)
BEGIN
       -- 2. insert data
       EXECUTE IMMEDIATE format("""
              INSERT INTO `peterwu..UDP_OUTPUT_mem_profile_aggregated`
              (TITLE, GROUP_ORDER, GROUP_ID1, GROUP_NAME, MEM_CNT, TKT, SALES)
              SELECT @title_name
                     , 5
                     , COUNT(DISTINCT MEM_ID) MEM_CNT
                     , COUNT(DISTINCT CASE WHEN IS_TICKET = 1 THEN TKT_NO END) AS TICKET
                     , SUM(retail_price_amt) SALES
              FROM `peterwu.tlw_txn_since_2017`
              WHERE TRANS_DT BETWEEN @start_dt AND @end_dt
              AND MEM_ID IN (SELECT MEM_ID FROM `"""||table_name||"""`)

              /*========== FILTER CONDITION CONTROLED BY USER INPUT: FILTER 1 OR FILTER 2=========*/
              -- FILTER 1 --
              AND 
              ( 
                  SITE_ID BETWEEN '1A01' AND '1A02' OR
                  SITE_ID BETWEEN '1A03' AND '1A04'
              )
              AND
              -- FILTER 2 --
              ( 
                  SITE_ID BETWEEN '1S01' AND '1S02' OR
                  SITE_ID BETWEEN '1S03' AND '1S04'
              )
       """)
       USING status_start_dt as start_dt
             , status_end_dt as end_dt
             , title_name as title_name;       
END
```

Comment: Hi @Pete,Did the answer below help you in resolving the issue?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

here's my sample code which is trying to do what you want.

basically to answer you question, it is possible to use conditional expression evaluated in the where clause. here I have assumed the input condition are two and can be assigned to two input variables and based on which where clause can be evaluated.

```
CREATE OR REPLACE PROCEDURE myproject.zz_DataSet.procTest
                            ( title_name STRING
                             , condition1 string
                             , condition2 string)
BEGIN

  EXECUTE IMMEDIATE format ("""
    INSERT INTO myproject.zz_DataSet.zzProcTest (TITLE_NAME)
    SELECT firstname
    FROM myproject.zz_DataSet.tblOne
    WHERE "condition1" = if(@c1 is null,@c2 ,@c1)
    """
  )
  USING condition1 as c1,
        condition2 as c2;
END;
```

here's my call to procedure. in this case condition 1 is evaluated to true and hence inserts condition1 in table tblOne. hope this helps

```
call myproject.zz_DataSet.procTest("condition1","condition1","")
```