# How to pass table as a parameter and use that table to update inside a function using Big Query

Tags: function, google-bigquery, parameters, datatable

I created a function that has to update a table based on different condition. The function looks like below but the problem is that I need to pass table as a parameter and use it to update it. I tried to pass table name as a `string` and use it which didn't work that throws error near `UPDATE` stating that `Syntax error: Unexpected identifier "table_name" at` and also tried to declare the table name parameter as table but still  throws error near `UPDATE` stating that `Syntax error: Unexpected identifier "table_name" at`. How do I pass the table as a parameter and update it?

Function:-

```
CREATE TEMP FUNCTION test_replace(Rule_name STRING,Rule_id INT64, table_name TABLE,column_name STRING) AS (
  CASE 
    WHEN Rule_name = 'test_2' THEN (
      UPDATE  table_name
      SET
        rule_id = Rule_id
      WHERE  column_name =  'test_2';
    )
    WHEN Rule_name = 'test_1' THEN  (
      UPDATE  table_name
      SET
        rule_id = Rule_id
      WHERE  column_name =  'test_1'
   )
  END
);
```

Comment: similar use case with procedures is achievable. see https://stackoverflow.com/questions/75370185/dynamic-filter-condition-in-bigquery-procedure/75372011#75372011